# ScheduledExecutorService throwable lost

Tags: java, exception, executorservice

Consider I scheduled a Runnable for periodic execution with ScheduledExecutorService and there occurs some system Error like OutOfMemory. It will be silently swallowed.

```
scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                      throw new OutOfMemoryError(); // Swallowed
                    }
                }, 0, delay, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Is it normal?

Why doesn't it propagate to the container?

What is the correct way to handle such errors?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `OutOfMemoryError`, like any subtype of `Error`, cannot be recovered from, they're generally fatal to your program. It doesn't really matter if you try and catch it or not, your program's going down.

If, however, you mean an `Exception` rather than an `Error`, then you have 2 options:

1. Catch the exception from within your task's `run()` method.
2. Call `get()` on the `Future()` returned by `scheduleWithFixedDelay()`. This will propagate the exception back to the submitting thread, but it will block until that happens.

Answer (score 1):

The method will return a ScheduledFuture instance, which get methods (with or without a timeout) will throw an ExecutionException with your OutOfMemoryError as cause.

Comment: So you advice to always call future.get() after scheduling repeatable task? But that will cause creation of sleeping threads. Is it OK?

Comment: Well, you can't know if your job threw an exception or not until it is finished, so somehow you have to wait for it either to complete successfully or to fail (throw an Exception or Error). If you call get with a timeout of 0, the method will throw a TimeoutException if the job is still running. You don't have to block your thread to query the status of the returned Future.

Answer (score 0):

The [ListenableFuture](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture.html) class from [guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) may be useful here.

With this you can create an exception handler task that logs the error then attempts to restart the failed task.

You still need a sleeping thread to watch for exceptions, but you only need one global exception handler thread for the whole process (rather than one for each scheduled task.)

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would give your object sone kind of mechanism to report exceptions, rather than expect a framework to handle them. Think of an exception listener or similar.

For an oom, there is little you can do.

These executors ate there to execute your stuff not to handle all the possible problems that your code may have!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`VerboseRunnable`](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-log/apidocs/com/jcabi/log/VerboseRunnable.html) class from [jcabi-log](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-log), which catches all exceptions and logs them:

```
import com.jcabi.log.VerboseRunnable;
Runnable runnable = new VerboseRunnable(
  Runnable() {
    public void run() { 
      // do business logic, may Exception occurs
    }
  },
  true // it means that all exceptions will be swallowed and logged
);
```

Now, when anybody calls `runnable.run()` no exceptions are thrown. Instead, they are swallowed and logged (to SLF4J).